# How to compare the time complexity of $n^n$ and $2^{n\log_2(n^2)}?$

Tags: limits, derivatives

Here is what I did for this, using $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ to get the result.

$$2^{n\log_2(n^2)}=2^n\cdot2^{\log_2(n^2)}=2^n\cdot n^2$$

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{n^n}{2^n\cdot n^2}=\frac{n^{n-2}}{2^n}$$

then I stuck here, how should I compare $n^{n-2}$ and $2^n\;?$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thank you, I will change it to the mathematics writing

Comment: The first step is wrong though, you’re rewriting the exponentiation wrong. Use $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$.

Comment: @HelenGuo, $$2^{n\log_2(n^2)}=2^n\cdot2^{\log_2(n^2)}$$ is not correct, indeed it results that $$2^{n+\log_2(n^2)}=2^n\cdot2^{\log_2(n^2)}.$$

Comment: @Angelo you are right, I mixed that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your expression $\dfrac{n^n}{2^n\times n^2}$ it should be more obvious when written $\left(\frac n2\right)^n \times \frac 1{n^2}$.

The term in $\frac 1{n^2}$ really changes nothing, indeed you can easily show $n^2<2^n$ for $n\gg 1$.

So you get something $>\left(\frac n4\right)^n\to\infty$

---

But you got the first simplification wrong, you did $2^{ab}=2^a2^b$ (this is $2^{a+b}$ instead).

I think the easiest way to go is to express everything in the natural logarithm

$\displaystyle 2^{n\log_2(n^2)}=\exp\Bigg(n\times\frac{\ln(n^2)}{\ln(2)}\times\ln(2)\Bigg)=\exp(n\ln(n^2))=\exp(2n\ln(n))=n^{2n}$

Now you have to compare $n^n$ and $n^{2n}$.

Comment: Oh, right! I did it in wrong way, I mixed the $2^{(ab)}$ and $2^{(a+b)}$, thank you